# How to open java based web application in a KIOSK mode?

Tags: java, web-applications, kiosk-mode

We have a java based web application. The web application is used to conduct exams. Is it possible to run the application in kiosk mode so that when students are accessing it, its opened in a kiosk mode so that students cant do anything else on the system till the exam is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The kiosk-ness is purely a client side phenomenon. The server side webapp doesn't know or care about that, as it just serves requests.

Even if it did know, it couldn't reliably prevent the user from doing forbidden things. Generally a kiosk-mode application isn't a webapp, because it has to prevent things like running outside applications, going to user selected URLs, and other such things which are a lot easier to block in a native application than inside a browser window.